# How to use ruby on rails named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I defined nested resources like this

```
resources :item, :only => [:create, :destroy, :update]  do
    resources :item_image, :only => [ :new, :create, :show ,  :destroy, :index]
end
```

And my routes look like this (output of rake routes)

```
item_item_image_index GET    /item/:item_id/item_image(.:format)     item_image#index
                     POST   /item/:item_id/item_image(.:format)     item_image#create
 new_item_item_image GET    /item/:item_id/item_image/new(.:format) item_image#new
     item_item_image GET    /item/:item_id/item_image/:id(.:format) item_image#show
                     DELETE /item/:item_id/item_image/:id(.:format) item_image#destroy
```

I thought the first column of the output is "the named routes".

I want to show a path to /item/:item_id/item_image(.:format) in one of my view.

```
item_item_image_index GET    /item/:item_id/item_image(.:format)     item_image#index
```

I tried this:

```
<%= link_to "users", item_item_image_index  %>
```

and also this

```
<%= link_to "users", item_images_path  %>
```

Neither works

I got  "undefined local variable or method `item_images_path/item_item_image_index'" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try:

```
<%= link_to "users", item_item_image_index_url(@item) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "users", item_item_images_url(@item)  %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "users", item_item_image_index_path(@item)  %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "users", item_item_images_path(@item)  %>
```

don't forget the url needs an :item_id, hence you need to pass an item as an argument.

actually, you should avoid naming that model "ItemImage". An Item has Images, that's what you need to know. you'll get better helper names like "item_images_url"

Comment: Thank you, that works. One extra question, why the POST DELETE routes in my routes do not get auto generated path name?

Comment: never mind, figured that out by my self. they all have same path,  only difference is HTTP verbs .

Comment: exactly. url helpers are nice specially for anchor tags. POST/PUT/DELETE  methods usually involve a form, where you have to specifically state (depending of the form helpers) the HTTP verb alongside the url. (I'm assuming you're not using the horrible Rails js hacks for anchor tags with :remote => true)

Answer (score 1):

```
item_item_image_index GET    /item/:item_id/item_image(.:format)     item_image#index
```

In this route `item_item_image_index`, you need a `item_id` in the url

Lets you have an object of Item model named as @item, then your link will be

```
<%= link_to 'users', item_item_image_index_path(@item) %>
```

Here You need to append '_path' after the route helper "`item_item_image_index`". While passing the `@item` variable, it will take the `@item.id` as `item_id` and completes the URL of the link.