# Rails uncountable model name, no route matches get name_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model with uncountable name - `class Equipment` and in this article (https://markembling.info/2011/06/uncountable-nouns-rails-3-resource-routing) I found that in such cases we get into problems while trying to get model's index path. So article provides tips how to use inflection rules. However, I believe word 'Equipment', just like 'person' is already understood by Rails and I dont even need to define inflection rule, since I still get this path:

> equipment_index GET    /equipment(.:format)                             equipment#index

But, for some reason, after I navigate to localhost:3000/equipment_index, I get

> No route matches [GET] "/equipment_index"

All other paths works (like localhost:3000/equipment).

Any ideas whats going on..?

p.s. please do not write how to add a custom path. I hope to solve this in the Rails way - convention over configuration. Thanks.

routes:

```
     equipment_index GET    /equipment(.:format)                         equipment#index
                     POST   /equipment(.:format)                         equipment#create
       new_equipment GET    /equipment/new(.:format)                     equipment#new
      edit_equipment GET    /equipment/:id/edit(.:format)                equipment#edit
           equipment GET    /equipment/:id(.:format)                     equipment#show
                     PATCH  /equipment/:id(.:format)                     equipment#update
                     PUT    /equipment/:id(.:format)                     equipment#update
                     DELETE /equipment/:id(.:format)                     equipment#destroy
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'generate_raport'
    end
  end
  resources :client_users
  resources :clients
  devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
  resources :equipment
  root to: 'static#homepage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is convention over configuration!

You're simply reading the output of `rake routes` wrong or have the wrong expectations about how its supposed to work. The first column is just the name of the route which is primarily used for creating path helpers. The actual paths are in the third column*.

```
equipment_index_path() # /equipment
equipment_path(1) # /equipment/1
equipment_path() # error due to missing id param
```

Since equipment is an uncountable noun Rails cleverly avoids an issue where the generated path helpers would be ambiguous - `equipment_path` could potentially lead to either the index action or the show action. Regular countable nouns don't have this issue so the `_index` postfix is not usually needed.

```
# no ambiguity 
cats_path() # /cats
cat_path(1) # /cats/1
```

While you could argue that rails in that case should use the presence of the `id` param to differentiate that is not how its built and could mask bugs where you pass nil instead of a record.

Comment: * technically its the pattern used to match the request uri.

Comment: I had a nightmare about this, since I went to sleep already knowing that this convention is already in and all is fine. My mistakes - not having titles on index and show pages and somehow forgotten that show page url must contain an id...

Answer (score 3):

`equipment_index` is a [named route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036721/how-to-use-ruby-on-rails-named-routes), not a url string. The url string that corresponds to this named route is in this part:

```
GET /equipment(.:format)
```

When you say:

> equipment_index GET /equipment(.:format) equipment#index

you are really saying that `equipment_index` is a named route (an alias so to say) for the actual url route `localhost:3000/equipment`. The last part that says:

> equipment#index

just says that your request will be routed through the `equipment` controller and the corresponding `index` action.

### Solution

You can simply navigate to `localhost:3000/equipment` to get to the `index` page for your `equipment` controller.

For example, you would link to this page using a rails `link_to` helper and the named route discussed above like this:

```
link_to "My index path", equipment_index_path
```

### Follow up on comments

change add the following line to your routes.rb file directly after the line that contains `resources :equipment`. It would now look like:

```
resources :equipment
get 'equipment', to: 'equipment#index', as: 'equipment'
```

Comment: Hi, ok, I will read more anout named routes, but I have another model User and route - `users GET    /users(.:format)  users#index` is completaly the same and I can get to it simply by `localhost/users`. Could you explain that also?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't totally understand. What exactly would you like me to explain? Also, could you update your post with your routes.rb file?

Comment: updated. As you can see, `equipment` is used for the show action. And it works fine. And from the articles I have read, all this should work fine, I dont know what I might be missing...

Comment: You posted the result of typing `rake routes`, but you can you paste your entire `routes.rb` file as well? I think I have an idea of what's wrong but i need to see your routes file first.